# How to check every checkboxes in a jquery datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatable

I have a table with checkboxes in the first column. I use the jQuery DataTable plugin display my table.

I made 2 links to select/unselect every checkboxes. Here's the one to select all :

```
<a href="" name="CheckAll" onClick="checkAll(document.email_list_form_inviter.getElementsByClassName(\'email_checkbox\'), event)" >Select all</a>
```

And the javascript :

```
function checkAll(field, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
        field[i].checked = true ;

    return false;
}
```

But the datatable enables pagination and my function select only the visible checkboxes, not those of the other pages. How can do to select every checkboxes in my data table?

Solution :

Ok I did this with fnGetNodes, thank you amccausl!

```
$("a[name='CheckAll']").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var nodes = datatable.fnGetNodes( );
        $('.email_checkbox', nodes).attr("checked", "checked");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fnGetNodes](http://datatables.net/api#fnGetNodes) to grab all the nodes you need, instead of the getElementsByClassName.

You should also be using jquery.click() event instead of defining an onClick yourself

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution (DataTables1.9.4):

```
var nodes = $('#listContainer').DataTable().column(0).nodes();
    $(':checked', nodes).each(function (index) {
        console.log($(this).text())
    })
```

Comment: The first line of the code is to get all the nodes instance which is the prarent nodes including the checkboxs; So we can get the all checkboxes by using the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, my code is wrong :

The dynamic checkbox

```
return '<input type="checkbox" id="email_checkbox" name="email_checkbox"  />';
```

The link

```
<a href="" name="CheckAll" id="CheckAll">seleccionar todos</a>
```

the name´s table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" width="100%">
```

and the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a[name='CheckAll']").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var nodes =  $('#example').fnGetNodes( );
                $('.email_checkbox', nodes).attr("checked", "checked");
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".checkall").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
                var nNodes = oTable.fnGetNodes();
                $email_box=$('.email_checkbox',nNodes);
                if($email_box.attr("checked")=="checked"){
                  $email_box.removeAttr("checked");
                  $(".checkall").text("Check all");
                }
               else{
                 $email_box.attr("checked", "checked");
                 $(".checkall").text("Uncheck all");
             }
});
```